# How secure if automount of ecryptsfs in Synology NAS

Tags: ecryptfs, synology

I'm using automount for my ecryptfs folders in the Synology NAS. I'm wondering where the Key Manager stores the keys and how easy it is to read my encrypted folders in case of theft of the NAS.

I assume that by taking a disk and mounting it on another system the key is readable. But maybe the NAS has a small flash to store the keys what would make this a bit more difficult.

I'm thinking of using a external password provider in the network that then probably will be forgotten to steal or read. So just use an ESP8266 with the key and use a script in the NAS to read that key and mount the folders. Some kind of automated manual mount.